# classList.toggle() only works one time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to implement a different pop-up window when I click different divs. Here's an example:

```
<div class="column" onclick="togglePopup('popup', 2)">Residential cleaning</div> <!--Function used here. -->
                        <div id="overlay">
                            <div class="popup">
                                <div class="popup_content">
                                    <div class="close_btn" onclick="closePopup('popup',2)">&times;</div>
                                    <h1>Some heading</h1>
                                    <p>SOME TEXT</p>
                                    <img src="assets/some_image.jpg" alt="image" width="249">
                                </div>
                            </div> <!--END of the popup window -->
                        </div>
```

When I click on the div of class column, I should see the popup div, however it only works with the very first one. Here's the JavaScript:

```
function togglePopup(popup_class, div_num){
    overlay.style.display="flex";
    let all_divs = document.getElementsByClassName(popup_class);
    let my_div = all_divs[div_num-1];
    my_div.classList.toggle("active");
    console.log(my_div)
    
}

function closePopup(popup_class, div_num){
    overlay.style.display="none";
    let all_divs = document.getElementsByClassName(popup_class);
    let my_div = all_divs[div_num-1];
    my_div.classList.toggle("active");
    console.log(my_div)
}
```

The function saves all the divs of class popup in the let all_divs, then it uses the parameter div_num to select a specific div and finally toggle the class "active" (CSS will be below). But like I said it only works one time. By the way the id overlay is originally hidden.
CSS:

```
.popup.active .popup_content {
    transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1);
}

#overlay  {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    z-index:1;
    display:none;
}
```

I really don't know why this happens, it works as intended only with the first element of the list "all_divs". Is there a way around this? I already tried many things and realized it only works on the first element of the list. I did not include the first div in the code, (the one that works) because it's the exact same thing, except instead of a 1 in onclick="togglePopup('popup', 1)" it has a 2.

Comment: Try changing `my_div.classList.toggle("active");` to `my_div.classList.remove('active');` within `closePopup`.

Comment: It looks like it might be getting triggered twice on the same element by togglePopup and closePopup.

Answer (score 5):

You're attempting to access a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) by an index that does not exist.  e.g.

```
let all_divs = document.getElementsByClassName('popup');
let my_div = all_divs[2]; // undefined
```

Instead you should add data to the open button to explicitly describe which popup it should open by its unique id.

Also, you should:

- use `querySelectorAll` to `addEventListener` to each of the relevant buttons
- use html buttons instead of divs

```js
const openBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.open_btn')
const closeBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.close_btn')


openBtns.forEach(openBtn => openBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const popupIdToOpen = e.currentTarget.dataset.popup;
  const popupToOpen = document.querySelector(`#${popupIdToOpen}`)
  if (popupToOpen) {
    popupToOpen.classList.add('active')
  }
}))

closeBtns.forEach(closeBtn => closeBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const popupToClose = e.currentTarget.closest(".overlay")
  if (popupToClose) {
    popupToClose.classList.remove('active')
  }
}))
```

```css
.overlay {
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="open_btn" data-popup="popup1">Popup 1</button>
<div class="overlay" id="popup1">
  <button class="close_btn">&times;</button >
  <h1>Popup 1 heading</h1>
  <p>Popup 1 Content</p>
</div>

<button class="open_btn" data-popup="popup2">Popup 2</button>
<div class="overlay" id="popup2">
  <button class="close_btn">&times;</button >
  <h1>Popup 2 heading</h1>
  <p>Popup 2 Content</p>
</div>

<button class="open_btn" data-popup="popup3">Popup 3</button>
<div class="overlay" id="popup3">
  <button class="close_btn">&times;</button >
  <h1>Popup 3 heading</h1>
  <p>Popup 3 Content</p>
</div>
```